# Passing params from Angularjs to Django

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, restangular

I'm seeing something unexpected inside the view (debugger mode), I'm not sure if I'm making a mistake in the frontend or backend:

```
(Pdb) request.QUERY_PARAMS
<QueryDict: {u'types': [u'Component', u'Core']}>
(Pdb) request.QUERY_PARAMS['types']
u'Core'
```

I am expecting to get `[u'Component', u'Core']`, rather than just a single element.

In the frontend, I'm using Restangular like so:

```
var params = {
    types: ['Component', 'Core']
};
Restangular.all('search').getList(params)...
```

Backend code is just inside the DRF queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = self.request
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    ...
```

Do I need to do some special encoding for the list of strings, or perhaps some other issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `request.QUERY_PARAMS.getlist('types')` because `request.QUERY_PARAMS` AKA `request.GET` is a django QueryDict. See the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

Comment: Somewhat related question: if I pass `[1,2,3]`, the integers get converted to string, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @WBC there is no way for Django to know the type of a value submitted in the query string so they will always be strings. You'll need to do something like `[int(q) for q in request.QUERY_PARAMS.getlist('types')]`. You could create a Django form and use a `TypedMultipleChoiceField` but this amounts to the same thing.

Comment: thanks so much...since you mentioned list comprehension, is there a performance difference here between `[int(q) for q in list]` vs `map(lambda x: int(x), list)` ?

Comment: Not a difference that would matter. Usually it is better to go with the more idiomatic approach i.e. list comprehension